# How do I get a secondary IPv4 address from an EC2 Instance using Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am building some EC2 instances in AWS using CloudFormation. One of the EC2 host have 2 network interfaces with IP addresses configured on different subnets.

I am able to obtain the IP address on the primary network interface using Cloudformation with:
!Sub ${SomeEC2.PrivateIp}

However, I need the secondary private IP address. How do I call the second network interface IP address using Cloudformation, and the !Sub function?

Comment: Are you creating a `AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface` resource in the template? If so, could you use `PrimaryPrivateIpAddress` on the additional ENI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I call the second network interface IP address using Cloudformation, and the !Sub function?

Sadly, you can't do it using plain CloudFormation (CFN). You would have to develop your own [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). The resource would be in the form of a **lambda function**, which would take instance id as a parameter, and then use AWS SDK to obtained the second IP address. The address would be returned to your CFN stack for further processing.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case. Thanks Marcin for the response and documentation.